# Mediaplayer prepare showing Illegal State Exception

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, illegalstateexception

I am trying to play an audio file from the internal storage. 
The code I used is..

```
package com.abhi.firstapp.firstapp;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
         setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    File f= new File("/sdcard/a.mp3");
    if(f.exists())
    {

        Toast toast= Toast.makeText(this, "file exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        Log.d("uri","1");
        Uri uri= Uri.fromFile(f);
        Log.d("uri", "2");

        mp= new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        Log.d("uri", "3");

        try {
            mp.setDataSource("/sdcard/a.mp3");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //mp.setDataSource(getBaseContext(), uri);
            Log.d("uri", "4");


        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("uri", "IOException");
        }

        mp.start();


    }
    else {
        Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(this, "file does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast1.show();
    }

    //MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), uri);
    //mp.start();

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

By using the log, I can determine that this code is running till the mp.prepare(mediaplayer prepare). And on this step, it gives the error Illegal State Exception

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a couple of things you might want to change.

First: `mp.prepare()` will  block your main thread, which is forbidden and will result in an exception where Android will close your app. To prevent this, `mp.prepareAsync` was designed. Use that method instead and implement both an onPreparedListener and an onErrorListener.

Second: you should provide a datasource before you call prepare().

You could do this for example this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try { 
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(streamURL);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Error, do something
        }

        mp.prepareAsync();
        ...
    }
        @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: I see that he did call setDataSource before the prepare in the original code..

So why was the answer accepted? Was the IllegalState due to calling prepare() instead of prepareAsync()? I have a similar problem, and I'm still calling prepare() but I do it from a background thread, so it should work, right?

Comment: This answer might be helpful to folks looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53390067/826946

Comment: What is the usage of"implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener" to the activity if you don't use it. useless

Comment: @LasithaLakmal - `@override public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player)` implements `OnPreparedListener`, which is the interface that is most relevant to this question.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. It can be raised because MediaPlayer is already prepared. When you create a new MediaPlayer by `MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),someUri);` mp prepares automatically so you should not prepare it by yourself.