# Android Mediaplayer Null point Exception (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to create Mediaplayer session with given uri. but it causes **NullpointerException**.

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

    // Creating MediaPlayer with given song's URI
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);

    try {
        // Setting the MediaPlayer Listener
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                mediaPlayer.start();
                changeSeekbar();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
    }
```

Given Logcat:

```
2020-04-07 22:21:05.289 12237-12237/com.example.musicappresearch2 E/Path: /storage/emulated/0/Music/Alone - Viren.mp3
2020-04-07 22:21:05.289 12237-12237/com.example.musicappresearch2 E/ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer$OnPreparedListener)' on a null object reference
```

Could you Tell me What i am doing wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: According to logs shared, your mediaPlayer object is not instantiated and it is null and hence application is giving NPE when tried to invoke setOnPreparedListener method on it. Can you add null check for mediaPlayer before invoking method on it and try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mediaplayer prepare showing Illegal State Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079310/mediaplayer-prepare-showing-illegal-state-exception)

Comment: This can help you https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer

Comment: None of theese helped. Actually this worked for API 23 but now in Android 10 it gives NPE

Comment: How are you getting the Uri? Through an intent?

Comment: through Singleton (with Arraylist of SongModels). i tested and the patch was right before initializing mediaplayer. so have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to write this code, both tested on the device

**First of all, make sure you handle `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` correctly and you really have correct Uri.**
`MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);` will fail if either context or uri are invalid.

`MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);` which itself already prepares player so you **don't need** `.prepareAsync()` in this situation. and your code is good to go.

another way:

```java
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); // hence, we don't use .create, manually instantiate
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, uri);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        });

        /* use async, if you don't want to block UI thread
         keep in mind, this should be called after setting listener  
       because it might prepare even until the listener has been set */
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
           // mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(uri));
           mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this,uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: This solution gives IllegalStateException on mediaplayer.prepare()